# issue is setFocusOnLoad not working VF page

Tags: visualforce

We have tried below code.

```
function setFocusOnLoad(){ /*NOOP*/ }
```

This function is not overwriting in VF page.

My Question is, we have `Apex:form` and some inputs(text, check box and command button). If I click on any place of the form, it called the first input action("Submit" button). So we want avoid this call without click on Button.

Could you please give the steps.